# Problem in using COZIR W-100 with arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors

I was using the COZIR W-100 carbon dioxide sensor with an Arduino Mega 2560 with the example code from [this site](http://www.co2meters.com/Documentation/AppNotes/AN128-%20Cozir_Arduino.pdf).

But the measured value of carbon dioxide by sensor was 90 ppm in fresh air and that is not correct. Please help me find the cause and a solution.

Comment: You're right. 90ppm is too [*low*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_in_Earth%27s_atmosphere).

Comment: Since that is a  20% CO2 sensor, should you multiply by 5?